# Are there any web service that could show any website analyze infomation?

Tags: web-services, api

Without integrating the code into the website , just get the info with typing in the url. 
Like this webservice do :  http://www.similarweb.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use follow.net.  Here is an example report on creditreport.com

http://follow.net/domains/creditreport.com